# Storing data into an XML under iOS

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, nsxmlparser

I'm using an NSXMLParser to read data out of a XML, but how can I make my iPhone App storing data into this specific XML.

The case is that I want to create an app to display available dates and one that administrates this dates, whether they are available or not (I'm using an UISwitch to handle this).

Thanks for your answers,

btype.

Answer (score 1):

If you have small amount of data, you can save them in a plist.

See [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)

Comment: Thank you, it works well, but how can I manage different Entries like in a XML, I have 1 Entry and different Attributes, do I have to create a new plist for each?

Comment: No, use a NSDictionnary at the root of the plist

Answer (score 0):

There's a github project that let's you create XML DOM objects.  You can save your XML to your documents folder on the phone.

https://github.com/arashpayan/apxml/